# Strangely behaviour of Vim documentation, E149 message helpfiles

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

This problem is getting me really crazy. I use Gvim under Windows 7. For various reasons, I use a .vim folder and .vimrc, instead the vimfiles and _vimrc for Windows. I want to maintain compatibility with UNIX/POSIX systems.

Everything is stored in Dropbox, so it get synced on various systems.

I fire my Gvim.exe. Everything worked, except the help files.

I use Pathogen, to manage my plugins. When I run the command :Helptags (is a feature of Pathogen), to make tagfile of the documentation from the plugins, it worked well.

For example, I can find the documentation of helpfiles, after :Helptags, like

```
 :help NERDTree
 :help Unite
```

This worked well. But strangely, I have no access to Vim own's documentation. When I look in the folder vim74/doc/, I see the Vim help files are stored, like version7.txt, eval.txt, options.txt, and so on. But when I run

```
:help autochdir
:help hidden
```

I get the E149 message: No help for help.txt

When I do:

```
 :echo &helpfile
```

I get C:\Dropbox\Vim\vim74\doc\help.txt. I checked, and the help.txt file is stored there.

On :echo $VIM C:\Dropbox\Vim.

On :echo $VIMRUNTIME, I get C:\Dropbox\Vim\vim74.

So this is driving me mad. I copied the contents of Vim74\doc to myownname\doc and did :Helptags from Pathogen, to create a tag file. After that, The doc files of the plugins are found by the tags. But Vim's own help documentation is still not found.

What is wrong here, and how could I find it out?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: In my case there was no `/usr/share/vim/vim90/doc/tags` file. So, I downloaded it from https://fossies.org/windows/misc/vim90rt.zip/vim/vim90/doc/tags and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

A fresh install of Vim, did solve my issue. :)

But it's still weird.